# Unable to correctly both verify invalid input and accept correct range values with C++

Tags: c++, validation

I am an amateur practicing code in C++ and I cannot get my code to work correctly. I am hoping that someone can find my issue or point me in the correct direction.

I am simply trying to create a switch/case menu for users to select from. I would like them to not be able to enter any incorrect values as input. the only correct values are 1,2,3 or 4. If there are any lower, greater, or non-numeric values entered I would like them to be stuck in a loop until they enter a correct value.

My issue with my working error check is that when they actually enter the correct values in they are still stuck in the loop?! I have tried rearranging my code, but then the error blows up my program again.

Thank you for any advice, code input, etc. I have no idea why it is not working!!!

And on a related note. I was having issues getting my jgrasp download to work correctly for c++ so i downloaded a compiler called code::block. for some reason it cannot register the system("") commands?! any ideas or a better compiler would be appreciated. thanks. oh and here is my code for my first issue... after the code is where my switch/case menu begins. thank you for any help

```
int main()
{
string name;
int ans2, ans3, count = 0, extra, select = 1, arraycount = 0, choice;
bool flag = true;
cout << "Hello World" << endl;
cout << "Enter your name: ";
cin >> name;
cout << "Thank you for using this program " + name << endl;
while (select != 4)
{
cout << "MAIN MENU\n";
cout << "Please enter a corrisponding numeric for your selection.\n";
cout << "1. You are Michael...\n";
cout << "2. You are Tim\n";
cout << "3. You are someone else\n";
cout << "4. Program exit\n";
cout << "Enter your selection: ";
cin >> select;

do
{
while(!(cin >> select))
    {
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout << "Invalid input.  Try again: ";
}
cout << "You entered: " << select << endl;

if (select != 1 && select != 2 && select != 3 && select != 4)
{
    flag = false;
    cout << "Error. Please enter a valid selection.";
    cout << "Enter your selection";
    cin >> select;
}
else
    flag = true;


}while(flag == false);

cout << "\n\nThank you for your choice\n";
//system("pause");
//system("cls");
```

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/istream-and-ignore.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a crowdsourced debugging forum. This question and its answer will not be useful to anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this part of your code ,

```
if (select != 1 && select != 2 && select != 3 && select != 4)
{
    flag = false;
    cout << "Error. Please enter a valid selection.";
    cout << "Enter your selection";
    cin >> select;
}
```

this part may be the cause of your problem as you input the select once again here, but you don't modify the flag value. You could add the check to `while(!(cin >> select))` as

```
 while(!(cin >> select) || select > 4 || select < 1)
```

Comment: i tried adding my != parameters to it once before. I will try it like that. right now though... that actually did it! I think i might have messed up my &&s and parenthesis when i tried that before. I bet i messed that up somehow. thanks alot. you sir have both optimized my code and saved my sanity!